# How would I reject a non numeric input using a C code?

Tags: c, cs50

I made a code using cs50.io (c). The only thing is that whenever I check50 in the terminal, I am getting an error message that states Rejects a non-numeric input + expected input... Here is my code and below it the errors in the terminal. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float celsius, fahrenheit;

    printf("\nEnter temp in Celsius : ");
    scanf("%f", &celsius);

    fahrenheit = (1.8 * celsius) + 32;
    printf("F: %.1f\n", fahrenheit);

    return (0);     
}
```

https://sandbox.cs50.net/checks/ef786d6473b2409381a7161c725f8776

Comment: Something like `while (scanf("%f", &celsius) != 1) printf("\nEnter temp in Celsius : ");` ??

Comment: a) check the return value from `scanf` and b) read a single character more and check it is a `newline`.

Comment: Note that the CS50 course comes with a library contained in source files `cs50.c` and `cs50.h`, and two of the functions defined are `GetFloat()` and `GetDouble()` which deal with these problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can check `scanf()`'s return value [Read the manual `scanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

```
float value;
if (scanf("%f", &value) != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "non numeric input rejected.\n");
else
    fprintf(stderr, "good the input is a number `%f'.\n", value);
```

the downside is that, subsequent input is generally difficult to handle with `scanf()` because it ignores white space characters, and you would need to manually remove them from `stdin`.

The way I like is,

```
char buffer[100];
float value;
char *endptr;
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
    return -1; // Something went wrong (Ctrl+Z/Ctrl+D -> EOF) perhaps
// Check if non numeric characters are present.
value = strtod(buffer, &endptr);
if (((isspace(*endptr) != 0) && (*endptr != '\0')) || (buffer == endptr))
    fprintf(stderr, "non numeric input rejected.\n"); // ^ no conversion happened
else
    fprintf(stderr, "good the input is a number `%f'.\n", value);
```

But this, is not perfect either since `"123.456 example"` would be considered a numeric value. Handling it rigorously is possible but requires more work. But I think you get the point with these examples.

Comment: Where would this go within the code? I am a little confused

Comment: @SamuelNazaroff You can create a function, it really depends on where you want to use it. This can be in `main()` per your sample code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with simply checking the return value of `scanf("%f",...);` is that you won't catch invalid characters that *follow* otherwise valid characters. This solution is simpler than others and does catch invalid characters before, in the middle of, or after numeric input:

EDITED: per @[WeatherVane's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) — [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141156/how-would-i-reject-a-non-numeric-input-using-a-c-code/34141427?noredirect=1#comment56031603_34141427)

```
char baddet; // a dummy var used merely for detecting bad scanf() conversions

.
.
.

if (scanf("%f%c", &celcius, &baddet) != 2 || baddet != '\n')
{
   printf("Invalid numeric conversion (non-numeric characters in the input).\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

If any non-numeric characters follow otherwise valid numeric characters, the first such character is captured in `baddet`. In your situation, you ***should*** be capturing a newline character; in other situations (such as processing command line arguments), you might expect no whitespace to follow the numeric characters at all; in that case, the return value of `scanf()` should be 1, and the value in `baddet` doesn't actually matter (though it's important to pass its address to `scanf()` anyway, in case there were any non-numeric characters that follow the otherwise numeric input characters).

Comment: This is wrong `"%c"` will capture the next whitespace character, do you think considering whitespace characters as invalid is correct? It's always too hard to use `scanf()`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `if (scanf("%f%c", &celcius, &baddet) != 2 || baddet != '\n')`?

Comment: @iharob - I think you may be correct; I didn't actually try it with the OP's code. I usually use this technique when processing command line parameters, where there is no whitespace bounding a parameter (unless the invoker deviously quotes their command line parameters with included whitespace). I think Weather Vane's modification would work for the OP's situation though.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I think you've fixed my oversight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** In the code you posted, there was no check that `scanf` actually worked. When I entered `foo` the code continued, having made no conversion from text to `float celsius`. However `celsius` has never been initialised, so the behaviour is undefined. In my case, the code printed `32.0` because `celsius` *just happened* to have a value of `0.0`.

You should check whether `scanf` did as expected, in your example it should have returned the value `1`. You can also check if the character that terminated the conversion of text to `float` was the one you expected, by scanning the following character, like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float celsius, fahrenheit;
    char nextch;

    printf("\nEnter temp in Celsius : ");
    if (scanf("%f%c", &celsius, &nextch) != 2 || nextch != '\n') {
        printf("Bad entry\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fahrenheit = 1.8 * celsius + 32;
        printf("F: %.1f\n", fahrenheit);
    }
    return 0;     
}
```

Function `scanf` now has 2 format specifiers, so its return value should be `2` and the following character is checked to be a `newline`.

Comment: If you'd like to make this fail try `123 \n`. `scanf()` is really not useful. But you made me think about `"%f%*[ \t]%c"`, it migh work.

Comment: @iharob why would they enter that? My answer demands a strict one-line (and not too difficult) entry. But you are right - `scanf` is clumsy and I would never attempt the syntax you recommend.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you explain to me where this should go in the code I'm pretty new to all this and I'm am not so smart as you can see.